# Integral and Series interchange with $\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos{(6x)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n}\cos^{4n}(5x)}{(2n)!}dx$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to understand conditions for swapping the integral and sum. In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4708253/2023-mit-integration-bee-regular-season-problem-16) question the following expression is used :

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos{(6x)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n}\cos^{4n}(5x)}{(2n)!} \ dx = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n}}{(2n)!}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos{(6x)}\cos^{4n}(5x) \ dx$$

Why is the swap allowed here? Is it because the series converges $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{(2n)!}=\cosh(\sqrt{2})$ and $\cos^{4n}(5x)\leq1$ for example?

Comment: Because of what you noticed in the series... Dominated Convergence Theorem can be applied, which leads to the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily check that
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n}\cos^{4n}(5x)}{(2n)!}$$
converges **uniformly** on $[0,\pi]$. This readily implies that
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos{(6x)}\sum_{n=0}^{m}\frac{2^{n}\cos^{4n}(5x)}{(2n)!} \ dx = \int_{0}^{\pi}\cos{(6x)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n}\cos^{4n}(5x)}{(2n)!} \ dx
$$
(either by the dominated convergence theorem or quite directly in this setting).
But
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos{(6x)}\sum_{n=0}^{m}\frac{2^{n}\cos^{4n}(5x)}{(2n)!} \ dx=\sum_{n=0}^{m}\frac{2^{n}\cos^{4n}(5x)}{(2n)!}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos{(6x)}\cos^{4n}(5x) \ dx
$$
and so taking limits you get
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos{(6x)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n}\cos^{4n}(5x)}{(2n)!} \ dx = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n}}{(2n)!}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos{(6x)}\cos^{4n}(5x) \ dx.
$$